# How to get Configuration->Application Setting from Azure APP Service using Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell, azure-app-service-envrmnt

[image]

The attached screenshot is from APP SERVICE in AZURE.

I am trying to get all the Application Setting values like "ACCOUNT_KEY", "ACCOUNT_NAME","app_name" using powershell code.

Please someone help me on this.

Comment: Any process on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get app settings from azure web with PowerShell, you could use [Get-AzureRmWebApp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.websites/get-azurermwebapp?view=azurermps-6.13.0) command to do it.

```
$destination = Get-AzureRmWebApp -ResourceGroupName GroupName  -Name WebName
$destinationAppSettings = $destination.SiteConfig.AppSettings
$destinationAppSettings
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry i was typing answer at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is a direct command available to retrieve appsettings via Powershell, However alternative ways is to use the [`Get-AzureRmWebAppSlotConfigName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.websites/get-azurermwebappslotconfigname?view=azurermps-6.13.0)

```
$source = Get-AzureRmWebAppSlot -ResourceGroupName $rsgName -Name $appName -Slot $slotName
```

Once you get the result, you need to iterate over **`$source.SiteConfig.AppSettings`**

Here is a [complete source](https://gist.github.com/sajeetharan/d80f55ef3c2b7d66420a3e1e348b9919)